Construct a function which is analytically integrable and which square is analytically integrable from given function and its derivative.
Suppose we have a function $f(x)$ and its derivative $f'(x)$ such that
$$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$$
cannot be expressed analytically (but $f(x)$ itself can).
Is there a way to construct a function $g(x) = g(f(x), f'(x))$ such that both integrals
$$\int_{0}^{1} g(x)dx$$
and
$$\int_{0}^{1} g^2(x)dx$$
can be computed analytically given any such function $f(x)$?
Bounds of integration were chosen arbitarily.
$g(x)$ needs to depend on at least one of $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ non-trivially, so $g(x) \equiv x$ is not an option.

What does it mean to assert that $\displaystyle\int_0^1f(x),\mathrm dx$ cannot be expressed analytically? It's a number.
